# python submit html form (sublime text plugin)

Tags: python, submit, sublimetext

I need to simulate html form submit via python [form like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/sthmj/embedded/result/) but from sublime text

I try code from [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231707/how-can-i-simulate-a-web-page-form-submit-with-a-python-code-behind) but it doesn't work for me it give error (No module named 'requests'):

```
import requests
payload = {'AAAWebView-FormAAA-field1': field1Value, \
    'AAAWebView-FormAAA-field2': field2Value, \
    'NAV__BUTTON__press__AAAWebView-FormAAA-enter': "enter"
}
url="https://host/path1/path2/AdapterHTTP?action_name=myactionWebAction&NEW_SESSION=true"
headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, files={})
print r.status_code
```

I'm absolutely new in python can someone give me a working example

I need to make sublime text plugin to push code from editor to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [Requests library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/2.2.1). For example:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: I don't think so I'll try to create sublime text plugin and it must work without install something like that

Comment: What don't you think? If you want to `import requests` you need to have it.

Comment: no, I need to use something already I have (sublime text have)

Comment: This answer shows a solution without extra libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/681182/1547831 (Python2 only)